# Cisco ASA TCP connections never time out

Tags: cisco-asa

Our Cisco ASA 5515 will sometimes have thousands of connections with an idle time > the configured connection timeouts. In many cases the connections show as idle for 100+ hours. This eventually leads to NAT/PAT exhaustion and we need to close connections manually. "show conn detail" will display tons of connections like this:

```
TCP Outside: XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX/443 Inside: YYY.YYY.YYY.YYY/#####, flags xA , idle 46D18h, uptime 146D4h, timeout -, bytes 0
```

However if I do `show running-config timeout`, it seems like all the timeouts are unchanged from the ASA default values:

Result of the command: `show running-config timeout`

```
timeout xlate 3:00:00
timeout pat-xlate 0:01:00
timeout conn 1:00:00 half-closed 0:10:00 udp 0:02:00 icmp 0:00:02
timeout sunrpc 0:10:00 h323 0:05:00 h225 1:00:00 mgcp 0:05:00 mgcp-pat 0:05:00
timeout sip 0:30:00 sip_media 0:02:00 sip-invite 0:03:00 sip-disconnect 0:02:00
timeout sip-provisional-media 0:02:00 uauth 0:05:00 absolute
timeout tcp-proxy-reassembly 0:01:00
timeout floating-conn 0:00:00
```

Why do my connections show a Timeout of `-`? I assume this is indicating that these connections will never time out. We only see this issue for TCP connections - UDP seem to timeout and close properly.

Comment: This question is probably a much better fit on [Network Engineering](http://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 1):

TCP is an actual two-way conversation between two hosts, and it has an inherent timeout. It has a specific sequence of events to create and end a conversation. The ASA knows about such things.

On the other hand, UDP is connectionless, and it requires a configured timeout so that the ASA can make a reasonable guess as to when a conversation is done.

Comment: What I'm struggling with is why the Cisco box shows idle time on the connections of 46 days, which are way in excess of the timeout settings. I'd assumed it would close those idle connections when they got to an hour of inactivity. Will repost on Network Engineering at your suggestion

Comment: TCP will be sending keepalive ACKs, so it's not like there isn't any activity, just no data transferred. If either side closes the conversation (FIN or RST), the connection will close.

Comment: I'd assumed the Idle time reported would reflect time since any communication, but perhaps it only reflects data transferred and not keepalives.

Comment: That's what I think since the TCP connection would be closed by one end or the other when its idle time is exceeded without any ACKs.